# Overleaf not working with pipe into lstlisting block of source code

Tags: font-encodings, characters

```
% %%%% Code Snippet START: %%%%
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
grep ^hello t.txt  # ok
grep ^hello t.txt | grep bye  # NOT SHOW THE PIPE!
grep ^hello t.txt \| grep bye  # NOT SHOW THE PIPE!
\end{lstlisting}
% %%%% Code Snippet END.   %%%%
```

---

Note. JSON snippets with similar problem on "{", "}" and '"'.

---

### Latex headers

The document-template that I am using.

```latex
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
%\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=ieee,
            uniquename=init,
            %giveninits,
            %repeatfields,
            %justify,
            %noslsn
            ]
            {biblatex}
            


%\urlstyle{same}

\addbibresource{referencias.bib}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}


\lstdefinestyle{SQL-Smarzaro}{%
    language=SQL,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    %    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    commentstyle=\color{gray},
    upquote=true,
    breaklines=true,
    morekeywords={*,REFERENCES,RENAME,TO,DATABASE,SCHEMA,IF,USE,REPLACE,REFRESH,MATERIALIZED, TYPE,
        BEFORE, AFTER, INSTEAD, OF, FOR, EACH, ROW, DO, STATEMENT, RULE, FUNCTION, PROCEDURE, WITH,...},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    %frame=ltrb,
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!20},
    inputencoding=latin1,
    extendedchars=true,
    %   autogobble=true,
    %escapeinside={(*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
    stringstyle = {\color{dkgreen}},
    %postgis
    morekeywords = [2]{st_distance, st_setsrid, st_point, st_transform, st_within, st_geogfromtext, st_area, st_contains, st_nrings, st_exteriorring, st_interiorringn,st_perimeter, st_npoints, st_endpoint, st_startpoint, st_length, st_X, st_Y, st_geometryn, st_numgeometries, multipoint, multilinestring, multipolygon, geometrycollection, polygon, linestring, point, st_covers, st_coveredby,st_geomfromtext, st_crosses, st_srid, st_setsrid, st_makepoint, st_pointfromtext,ST_LineFromText,st_IsSimple,st_IsValid, st_isclosed, st_isring, geography, geometry, st_equals,ST_OrderingEquals,st_disjoint,st_intersects, st_overlaps, st_touches,st_ContainsProperly, st_dwithin,st_relate,st_MakeLine, st_Union, st_Collect, st_Polygonize, st_centroid},
    keywordstyle = [2]{\color{blue}},
}


\lstset{style=SQL-Smarzaro,
    literate=
    {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
    {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
    {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
    {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
    {Ã}{{\~A}}1 {ã}{{\~a}}1 {Õ}{{\~O}}1 {õ}{{\~o}}1
    {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ű}{{\H{u}}}1 {Ű}{{\H{U}}}1 {ő}{{\H{o}}}1 {Ő}{{\H{O}}}1
    {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
    {€}{{\euro}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1 {«}{{\guillemotleft}}1
    {»}{{\guillemotright}}1 {ñ}{{\~n}}1 {Ñ}{{\~N}}1 {¿}{{?`}}1
}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no clear question proposed in the problem and there exists no complete code of which to compile.  This statement might not receive more than glance until otherwise fixed.

Comment: Hi @Leucippus, I added the headers (document template).

Comment: Have you tried adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` ?

Comment: @imnothere, now is working!  ...Delete the question?